# haproxy dynamic backend based on a host

Tags: haproxy

I have following configuration:

```
frontend example.com-https
    bind            1.1.1.1:443 ssl no-sslv3 alpn h2,http/1.1 crt /example.com.pem
    capture         request header Host len 40
    acl own_backend hdr(host) -i sub1.example.com

    ...

    acl own_backend hdr(host) -i subX.example.com

    use_backend %[req.hdr(Host),lower] if own_backend
    default_backend example.com

backend example.com
    server          worker1 2.2.2.2:80

backend sub1.example.com
    server          worker1 3.3.3.3:80

...

backend subX.example.com
    server          worker1 x.x.x.x:80
```

Is it possible to somehow remove *www* from HOST header in this part:
`use_backend %[req.hdr(Host),lower] if own_backend`
to reduce the number of backends? Because I have to write not only: "backend sub1.example.com" but also this "backend www.sub1.example.com".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into [regsub](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#7.3.1-regsub):

```
    use_backend %[req.hdr(Host),lower,regsub(^www\.,)] if own_backend
```

Tested with 2.3.10.